# Is SQL 2008 Express R2 really free like 2005 Express is?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

About to download it, keeps talking about "evaluation" and "evaluating SQL 2008 R2" and want to be sure it doesn't expire after 60 days or something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it's free and not limited to 60 days trial. Make sure you're downloading it from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/), just in case you've clicked on the wrong link.

I've just gone to download it and it's definately confusing wording, but it's probably refering to a newsletter or some other spam.

Comment: +1, i just grabbed it last Friday, and noticed the same thing. It really is free, the wording is a little off.

Comment: Yeah, I got it months ago and it's still working fine.

Comment: Odd, same link (copy/pasted from other IE), different browser (Chrome this time), and I'm not seeing the "evaluating" wording.  Maybe MS is watching our every moves! ;)